# High-precision random numbers on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, random, arc4random

I have been trying this for a while but thus far haven't had any luck.

What is the easiest way to retrieve a random number between two very precise numbers on iOS?

For example, I want a random number between 41.37783830549337 and 41.377730629131634, how would I accomplish this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Edit: I tried this:

```
double min = 41.37783830549337;
double max = 41.377730629131634;
double test = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * (max - min) + min;
NSLog(@"Min:%lf, max:%lf, result:%lf",min,max,test);
```

But the results weren't quite as precise as I was hoping, and ended up like this::

```
Min:41.377838, max:41.377731, result:41.377838
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can normalise the output of `rand` to any range you want:

```
((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * (max - min) + min
```

[*Note: This is pure C, I'm assuming it works equivalently in Obj-C.*]

[*Note 2: Replace `double` with the data-type of your choice as appropriate.*]

[*Note 3: Replace `rand` with the random-number source of your choice as appropriate.*]

Comment: I tried this: `double min = 41.37783830549337;
    double max = 41.377730629131634;
    double test = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * (max - min) + min;
    NSLog(@"Min:%lf, max:%lf, result:%lf",min,max,test);` --but it doesn't seem to give the precision I want, and echos out: Min:41.377838, max:41.377731, result:41.377838

Comment: @Oscar: That's an artifact of how you're formatting the numbers when displaying them.  I don't know Obj-C, but if `NSLog` works anything like `printf`, then trying using e.g. `%.15f`.

Comment: @Oscar: Note also that double-precision is equivalent to roughly 15-16 decimal places of accuracy.  If you need more than that, you'll need a more precise type.  But this is a separate issue than that of generating random numbers in a range.

Comment: I tried %.15f and it works perfectly, thanks! Looks like the old code I thought wasn't working before was working perfectly, and just echoing out incorrect results. Thanks again! Is there another type I should be using?

Comment: @OscarMcDonald: I'm not really qualified to say (I don't know Obj-C).  Perhaps there's such a thing as `long double`, or perhaps there's an arbitrary-precision floating point library available.  Like I said, that could be the subject of another question.